# Comparing Scala reflection Symbols

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-reflect

The [Types](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.5/index.html#scala.reflect.api.Types) Scaladoc page warns:

> Type Equality can be checked with =:=. It's important to note that == should not be used to compare types for equality-- == can't check for type equality in the presence of type aliases, while =:= can.

There is no similar warning for [Symbols](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.5/index.html#scala.reflect.api.Symbols), but looking at the [implementation](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/955eb2170e1291500813e6bec76a9f0e1e3bad50/src/reflect/scala/reflect/internal/Symbols.scala), it doesn't appear to override `equals`. Is there a way to compare symbols for equality (i.e. whether they represent the same Scala type/val/method/etc.)?

For `TypeSymbol`s I can obviously use `.toType` and `=:=`, so the question is primarily about `TermSymbol`s.

Comment: Just out of curiosity one would like to compare `TermSymbol`s? From my tests the equality works quite well, but that depends on what you would want to do with it.

Comment: `==` seems to work for `Symbol`, modulo the type parameters.

Comment: @m-z Do you mean for type symbols as well? It didn't work for me, but in a pretty complex scenario. I'll see if I can fix it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as though `==` is fine for symbols (to an extent). I don't want to try to over-interpret the scaladoc, but I don't think aliases matter with them. (I would also hope that the section on symbols would contain a similar warning.)

> Symbols are used to establish bindings between a name and the entity it refers to, such as a class or a method. Anything you define and can give a name to in Scala has an associated symbol.

versus `Type`:

> As its name suggests, instances of Type represent information about the type of a corresponding symbol. This includes its members (methods, fields, type aliases, abstract types, nested classes, traits, etc.) either declared directly or inherited, its base types, its erasure and so on. Types also provide operations to test for type conformance or equivalence.

The documentation suggests that `Type`s contain more valuable information than `Symbol`s.

Example:

```
type L[A] = List[A]

scala> typeOf[L[String]].typeSymbol == typeOf[List[String]].typeSymbol
res47: Boolean = true
```

The `Symbol`s are equal, even though the `Type`s are not. So while `L[A]` and `List[A]` have different `Type`s from the alias, they both resolve to the same `Symbol`. The inner-type information appears to be gone though, and the `Symbol` appears to contain the information on the `List` class itself.

```
scala> typeOf[List[String]].typeSymbol
res51: reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol = class List

scala> typeOf[L[String]].typeSymbol
res52: reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol = class List
```

So these are equal:

```
scala> typeOf[L[String]].typeSymbol == typeOf[L[Int]].typeSymbol
res55: Boolean = true
```

While these are not:

```
scala> typeOf[L[String]] =:= typeOf[L[Int]]
res56: Boolean = false
```

So while it appears while the underlying types should have the same `Symbol`, the `Symbol` might not contain all the information you need for the full comparison illustrated above.

Comment: The compiler ensures that symbols are unique. Even though there's no overridden Symbol.equals (i.e. we use Object.equals to compare symbols), there's an implementation-specific guarantee that using == (or eq, for that matter) for symbols is going to work as expected.